# Sum of point attributes inside hexagons using QGIS UI

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, point, statistics

I have a point shapefile that corresponds to locations of animals captured. I've joined a table to this shapefile with additional information on each attribute, namely nb. animals caught in each point. I have another shapefile (hexagonal grid) and my goal is to sum the nb. animals caught for each point that falls inside each hexagon. In a preliminary search on the web, I found that maybe "join by location" could help me do this, but the problem is that I'm getting an "incorrect field name" error, for a field that doesn't even exist in any of the original tables and, on the other hand, it won't let me select the specific field I want it to sum..

Any suggestions? Is there any way I can do this without going into writing scripts mode?

Comment: I was wondering if you had a chance to try the solution I posted below and if it was helpful to you at all

Answer (score 3):

There is another tool that does a good job for such purposes: In QGIS processing toolbox with SAGA data provider activated you may search for a tool called 'point statistics for polygons'. Herein you can provide your hexagons (polygons) and your animal observations as points, select an attribute to analyze and the statistical metrics you want.

I prefer this tool because QGIS 'join attributes by location' produces weird results under special circumstances, cp. [QGIS 'join attributes by location' algorithm produces strange results for min, max](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226639/qgis-join-attributes-by-location-algorithm-produces-strange-results-for-min-m)

(screenshot will be added)

Answer (score 2):

For the following procedure, let's assume your polygon layer is called `Po_lyr` and your point layer is called `pt_lyr`.

**Method 1:**

- Load the `Po_lyr` and `pt_lyr` into QGIS
- CLick on `Vector` -> `Analysis tools` -> `Points in Polygon`
- Load the `po_lyr` on top and the `pt_lyr` in the point layer selection menu
- Specify where you want the file to be saved
- Add the new layer to the map
- Right click on the map's name and chose `Open Attributes`
- The results should be there

**Method 2:**

- Load the `Po_lyr` and `pt_lyr` into QGIS
- CLick on `Vector` -> `Geoprocessing Tools` -> `Intersect`
- In the window that appears, the input layer is `pt_lyr` and the intersect layer is `po_lyr`
- Save the output shape file as `result_pt_in_poly.shp`
- Load that layer to to QGIS
- Right click on the layer again and click on `Attribute Table`
- At this point you can output the table to a spreadsheet and do the math there since for every point, you'll have the ID of the polygon in every point layer.
- If you want to still continue using QGIS, then I assume you'll have to use python console for that but someone here can correct me