# QGIS 'join attributes by location' algorithm produces strange results for min, max

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, spatial-join

In QGIS 2.14.11 LTR I have a point shapefile with (besides others) an attribute `kd` which is either `1` or `0` (never `NULL`) and a polygon dataset. I try to calculate minimum and maximum values for `kd` for each polygon containing points and I expect to be `minkd` and `maxkd` fields after to be either `1` or `0` also, but never `NULL` or any other values greater than `1`.

My `join attributes by location` algorithm is set up as follows:

[image]

As can be seen below (selected resulting polygon in the middle), values for `minkd` and `maxkd` are `6.000` in this case, but `NULL` and a variety of other values differing from `1` and `0` occur also.

[image]

I fairly can't understand how this behaviour can be explained, has anyone observed similar behaviour? Any hints to overcome this?

Comment: I have had an issue about that some days ago: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/16115  Is it the same?